# Ajax AutoCompleteExtender - automatically highlight first item

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is it possible to automatically highlight the first item of the list created by the Ajax Control Toolkit's AutoCompleteExtender?

I would like the first item to be highlighted the same way it would be if the user presses `down key` when the textbox is selected and the autocomplete list is visible. This would make the textbox be filled with the highlighted value if the user presses `tab` afterwards.

This is the code for the basic AutoCompleteExtender field:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="namebox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetNames"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1"
    CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10"
    TargetControlID="namebox"
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false"
    OnClientItemSelected="HandleChange_Name"
    >
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I completely missed the option `firstRowSelected` property already visible in the code of the question. It was enough to set it to `true`.

Eventually I found this reading the documentation in [the AutoCompleteExtender Wiki page](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/AutoComplete) on GitHub.